# Allocate EIP to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Attempting to associate an EIP (console allocated but not attached to any instance) to a running instance.  This instance has an IAM policy that allows it to AllocateAddress, AssociateAddress, DescribeInstances, DisassociateAddress, DescribeInstances, and iam:PassRole.

Expect to be able to call `ec2-associate-address -i i-some_instance_id some_eip`.

[NOTE]: `some-eip` actually does exist. I can see it on the aws dashboard

Yet keep getting the error `Client.AuthFailure: The address 'some_eip' does not belong to you`.

Also when I attempt to run `ec2-describe-addresses some_eip` I get this response `Client.InvalidAddress.NotFound: Address 'some_eip' not found`.

On the other hand, I am able to run `ec2-describe-instances --region us-east-1` as that returns all the instances in the supplied region.

The role was setup by our SysAdmin - and his permissions are different from mine. Would the above errors have anything to do with us having different user permissions?

Comment: BTW, these days it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than individual scripts like `ec2-describe-addresses`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for pointing that out. When you say script, I assume you mean a program I wrote myself: `ec2-describe-addresses` isn't a script; it is package created by the aws. See [this](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/EC2/ec2-clt.pdf). 

I might be wrong but I believe the AWS CLI does a whole lot more than EP2-API-Tools. Wouldn't it be better to install the tool with limited features that match what I need exactly?

Comment: It's actually a script stored in `/opt/aws/apitools/ec2-1.7.3.0/bin/ec2-describe-addresses` that calls `/opt/aws/bin/ec2-cmd`, which is also a script, which calls a Java webservices jar. In contrast, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) uses boto3, which is the Python SDK for AWS. It's also well-maintained, having updates available within days of releases (and sometimes before!).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ha! Did not know about and will update my answer. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This took a while but finally figured out region needs to specified for this to work. So correct method call is `ec2-associate-address -i i-some_instance_id some_eip --region some_region`.

The documentation for the method `ec2-associate-address` [ec2-api-tools](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/EC2/ec2-clt.pdf) does not indicate this though (thanks amazon).

PS: Please see the comments by John Rotenstein regarding the use of ec2-api-tools vs awscli. I am leaving this answer up because the tool I used was ec2-api-tools and not awscli.